# MySQL - COUNT(*) very slow

Tags: mysql, sql, innodb, mysql-slow-query-log

i have one table MySQL InnoDB with 130000 rows and the next query is very slow.

```
SELECT COUNT(id) FROM mytable;
```

OR

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM mytable;
```

Query_time: 12.020727

```
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field        | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| id           | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| id_user      | int(11)      | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| id_method    | int(11)      | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| date         | datetime     | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| type         | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| type_detail  | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
|id_manual_type| int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| obs          | longtext     | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| active       | tinyint(1)   | NO   |     | 1       |       |
| created_by   | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| created_at   | datetime     | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| update_by    | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| update_at    | datetime     | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+

EXPLAIN SELECT COUNT(id) FROM mytable;

+--------------+--------------+-------------------------+---------+---------+--------------+----------------+---------+-----+-------+----------+-----------+
| id           | select_type  |            table        | partions|  type   | possible_keys|        key     | key_len | ref | rows  | filtered | extra     |
+--------------+--------------+-------------------------+---------+---------+--------------+----------------+---------+-----+-------+----------+-----------+
|  1              SIMPLE      |             mytable     |  NULL   |  index  |   NULL       | id_manual_type |    4    | NULL| 130000|  100.00  |Using index|
+--------------+--------------+-------------------------+---------+---------+--------------+----------------+---------+-----+-------+----------+-----------+
```

What sort of optimizations on the database do I need to do?

- MYSQL 8.0.18
- Windows Server 2016
- 8GB RAM
- memory usage: 80%
- cpu usage: 30%

Comment: If the goal be to get the total record count, then `SELECT COUNT(*)` may already be the fastest option.  An index won't necessarily help much here.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen yes but 12 seconds is not a long time to execute this query?

Comment: What's the value of `innodb_buffer_pool_size`?

Comment: @RickJames default size of 128MB

Comment: @Moutinho - Change it to 5G.

Comment: Consider running ANALYZE TABLE mytable; to refresh your tables index content.

Comment: @RickJames you are correct. i change innodb_buffer_pool_size to 5G and the problem was solved. thanks!

Comment: @WilsonHauck it made no difference

Comment: Yeah, `ANALYZE TABLE` is harmless and _sometimes_ helps.